# Сгенерированные координаты выходят за пределы двумерного массива

Tags: javascript

Дана координатная плоскость 50х50, в случайной точке генерируется бомба (функция setBomb()), после взрыва нужно закрасить окружность, радиусом в 3 точки (функция soundSpread). Если бомба генерируется далеко от границ, то все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же бомба генерируется рядом с границами, то начинаются проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно заставить программу красить точки до тех пор, пока координаты не столкнутся с границами?

```
let field = document.getElementById('field')
    function addCell(field) {
        let coordinates = [], i, j;
        for(i = 0; i<50; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = new Array()
            for (j = 0; j<50; j++){
                let cell = document.createElement('div')
            cell.setAttribute('class','cell')
                cell.setAttribute('x',(i+1).toString())
                cell.setAttribute('y',(j+1).toString())
                coordinates[i][j] = cell
            field.appendChild(cell)
            }
        } return coordinates
    }
    
    let coordinates = addCell(field)
    
    function setBomb(coordinates) {
        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }
       let x = getRandomInt(coordinates.length)
        let y = getRandomInt(coordinates.length)
    
    
        let bombPlace = coordinates[x][y]
        bombPlace.setAttribute('class', 'affected')
       function soundSpread(x,y) {
            for(let i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    
                    coordinates[x+i][y+i].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x-i][y-i].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x+i][y-i].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x-i][y+i].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x+(i+1)][y].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x][y+(i+1)].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x-(i+1)][y].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
                    coordinates[x][y-(i+1)].setAttribute('class', 'affected')
    
    
            }
        }
       soundSpread(x,y)
    
    
    }
    
    setBomb(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setAffected(coordinates, x, y) {
  if (x >= 0 && x < coordinates.length && y >= 0 && y < coordinates[x].length)
    coordinates[x][y].setAttribute('class', 'affected');
}

...
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setAffected(coordinates, x + i, y + i);
    ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!